# Создать папку в Android 10

Tags: android

Почему программно не могу создать папку? Пытаюсь так:

```
File musicFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + AppConstants.dirName);
musicFolder.mkdirs();
```

Разрешение к хранилищу вручную выдала.

В манифесте такие разрешения

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

На реальном устройстве Redmi K20

Comment: Что значит "не могу"?

Answer (score 0):

Потому что вы игнорируете [ScopedStorage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage), а зря:

> To improve user privacy, direct access to shared/external storage devices is deprecated. When an app targets Build.VERSION_CODES.Q, the path returned from this method is no longer directly accessible to apps. Apps can continue to access content stored on shared/external storage by migrating to alternatives such as Context#getExternalFilesDir(String), MediaStore, or Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: Да, потому что хотела попробовала так. Читала что это временное решение. А как создаются папки и файлы начиная с android 10? Можно небольшой пример?

Comment: оформите новый вопрос - ответим

Comment: Создала: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1254864/Как-создать-папку-или-файл-используя-scoped-storage