# Как создать папку или файл используя Scoped Storage

Tags: java, android, android-scoped-storage

Как создать папку или файл в Android 10 используя Scoped Storage?

Сейчас есть метод, который работает на Android 9 и записывает в папку аудиопоток. Как его переделать под Android 10 и выше?

```
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

    isRecording = true;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlPath);
        InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();

        File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + AppConstants.dirName);

        if (!direct.exists()) {
            File musicFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + AppConstants.dirName);
            musicFolder.mkdirs();
        }

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + AppConstants.dirName, recordedFileName);
        System.out.println(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4*1024];
        int read;

        while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            if(isCancelled())
                break;
            outputStream.write(buffer,0,read);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Создаем каталог так:

1)Стартуем `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, примерно так:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION  |
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION  |
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
 startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_FOLDER);
```

2)Юзеру будет предъявлен системный файл селектор, в котором он сможет выбрать каталог

3)Ловим в `onActivityResult` выбранный юзером каталог, который обрабатываем примерно так:

```
//сначала получаем постоянный доступ на запись и чтение к каталогу
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
int takeFlags = intent.getFlags() & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION |
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
Uri folderUri = intent.getData();
contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(folderUri, takeFlags); 
//далее получаем ссылку на каталог в виде DocumentDile
DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, folderUri);
//создаем каталог
pickedDir.createDirectory("my_folder);
```

### Для создания файла

Надо запустить `Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` и поймать ссылку на него в `onActivityResult`

Comment: Спасибо, но есть вопрос как сохранить именно аудиофайл из потока? Я в вопрос добавила метод, который записывает аудио на андроид 9, можете ли подсказать как его переделать под андроид 10.

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна а можно не переделывать свой вопрос несколько раз?! Сначала был вопрос, почему нельзя создать каталог, потом вопрос переформулировался как создать каталог, а потом как записать? Можно быть более консистентным?

Comment: Ну и иногда хотя бы полезно плюсовать ответы...

Comment: Я ответила ваш ответ как правильный, но пока пытаюсь понять как он работает. Плохо поняла где писать первую часть вашего кода.

Comment: Сформулируйте еще один вопрос - только внимательно и чтобы не было бездумных дублей!

Comment: Тогда лучше почитайте, что такое `Intent` как его запускать и как ловить ответы на него... [туториал](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html)

Comment: Создавал вопрос выложив два класса, где все происходит. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1254893/Записать-аудиопоток-в-файл-на-android-10

Comment: Про интенты я знаю как запускаются, но запуталась. Было в одном виде, сейчас переделывать нужно под 10ый андроид поэтому небольшая путаница в голове. Да и следить за всеми обновлениями не получается.

Comment: Еще вопрос. В этой строчке startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_FOLDER); что такое REQUEST_FOLDER  ?

Comment: Значит вы не умеете запускать интенты... это некий идентификатор вашего запроса любой `int > 100` - вы его сами задаете, обычно `static final int`