# Записать аудиопоток в файл на Android 10

Tags: java, android

Есть приложение, которое воспроизводит аудиопоток из интернета и при нажатии на кнопку запись начинает записывать аудио в файл mp3. На Android 9 и ниже это работает, но из-за изменений доступа к хранилищу в Android 10 перестало работать (не создается папка и сам файл соответственно не записывается). Как переделать код под Android 10?

Класс Recorder

```
public class Recorder extends AsyncTask {

    private Context context;
    private String urlPath;
    private String recordedFileName;
    private boolean isRecording = false;

    public Recorder() {}

    public Recorder(Context context, String url, String recordedFilePath) {
        this.context = context;
        this.urlPath = url;
        this.recordedFileName = recordedFilePath;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

        isRecording = true;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlPath);
            InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();

            File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + AppConstants.dirName);

            if (!direct.exists()) {
                File musicFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + AppConstants.dirName);
                musicFolder.mkdirs();
            }

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + AppConstants.dirName, recordedFileName);
            System.out.println(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4*1024];
            int read;

            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                if(isCancelled())
                    break;
                outputStream.write(buffer,0,read);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    public void record()
    {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + AppConstants.dirName,recordedFileName);
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }

        this.execute();

    }

    public void stopRecording() {
        isRecording=false;
        this.cancel(true);
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String getUrlPath() {
        return urlPath;
    }

    public void setUrlPath(String urlPath) {
        this.urlPath = urlPath;
    }

    public String getRecordedFileName() {
        return recordedFileName;
    }

    public void setRecordedFileName(String recordedFileName) {
        this.recordedFileName = recordedFileName;
    }

    public boolean isRecording() {
        return isRecording;
    }

    public void setRecording(boolean recording) {
        this.isRecording = recording;
    }

}
```

AudioActivity

```
public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private String audioUrl;
    private String audioImg;
    private String audioTitle;
    private int audioID;

    public static boolean isPlay = false;

    private Recorder recorder; //Для записи аудиопотока
    private String recordedFileName = null; //Для записи аудиопотока
    private boolean isRecording = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ButterKnife.bind(this); //Для записи аудиопотока

        ***

    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btnStartRecord)
    public void onClickPlay() {

        if (!isPlay) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Запустите аудио", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            int permissionStatus = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            if (permissionStatus == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                reCreateRecorder();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Запись audio: " + audioTitle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                recorder.record();
                isRecording = true;
                btnStartRecord.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layoutTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnStopRecord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                mChronometer.start();
            } else { 
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        AppConstants.REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                layoutTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btnStopRecord)
    public void onClickPause() {
        btnStartRecord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        layoutTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnStopRecord.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        recorder.stopRecording();
        isRecording = false;
        mChronometer.stop(); //Останавливаем таймер
        Toast.makeText(this, "Файл сохранен в: " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                File.separator + AppConstants.dirName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        reCreateRecorder();
    }

    public void reCreateRecorder() {
        if (recorder != null) {
            if (recorder.isRecording()) recorder.stopRecording();
            recorder = null;
        }
        recordedFileName = "mymusic-" + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()/1000L + ".mp3";
        recorder = new Recorder(this, audioUrl, recordedFileName);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case AppConstants.REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { 
                    onClickPlay();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Нет доступа к хранилищу!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам придется сильно переделать код.

1)Запускаем `Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` - помещаете его в своем `Activity/Fragment`, привязав его например к меню или к какому-либо действию юзера (типа *а давай-ка запишем поток в файл*), примерно так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("*/mp3"); //не уверен, что у вас mp3
    String filename = "mymusic.mp3";
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, filename); //по сути подсказка юзеру какой файл надо создавать, но юзер может его изменить
    startActivityForResult(intent, MY_REQUEST_CREATE_FILE);
```

2)В том же `Activity/Fragment` ловите `onActivityResult()` там пишете код примерно такой:

```
Uri uri = intent.getData(); //URI создаваемого файла выбранного юзером
DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(this.getContext(), uri);
 // открываем поток для записи
fileStream = this.getContext().getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
```

3)Теперь у вас есть `fileStream` - поток куда надо записать ваш драгоценный аудиопоток. По желанию можете его оформить внутрь `AsyncTask` или чего-то подобного. По окончанию записи не забудьте закрыть поток.

Comment: Попробую сейчас переделать свой код. Отпишусь по результатам

Comment: Можете подсказать как в классе Recorder мне получить доступ к методу intent.getData()? Я выделила код записи аудио в другой метод в классе Recorder и хочу в нем реализовать в зависимости от версии андроид запись. но не знаю как получить доступ

Comment: Зачем вам в классе `Recorder` `Intent`? Передайте в конструкторе `intent.getData()` - он же `Uri`

Comment: Еще больше запуталась в общем. Сама запись у меня реализована в классе Recorder. Но как ваш код применить в нем не понимаю. Я бы хотела реализовать так: В классе PlayerActivity получить разрешение к хранилищу по нажатию на кнопку btnStartRecord (такая кнопка есть просто в классе убрала чтобы текст уменьшить), а затем вызвать методы из класса Recorder, где собственно и будет происходить запись в файл.

Comment: в `btnStartRecord` вызывайте `Intent`, в `PlayerActivity` ловите `onActivityResult` - в нем и вызывайте методы `Recorder`

Comment: Да, вот я вызвала в btnStartRecord интент на получение разрешения к хранилищу, в onActivityResult класса PlayerActivity хочу вызвать метод recorder.record - который записывает аудио. Но в методе record() класса Recorder как я могу получить Uri uri = intent.getData();? Это не могу понять.

Comment: А что передать его в параметре конструктора `Recorder` не судьба? Только не говорите, что не знаете что такое конструктор :)

Answer (score 0):

Сделала немного иначе. Следующим образом:

```
public class Recorder extends AsyncTask {

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

        isRecording = true;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            try {

                URL url = new URL(urlPath);
                InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, recordedFileName);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, 1);

                ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
                Uri collection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);

                Uri item = contentResolver.insert(collection, values);

                System.out.println(item.getLastPathSegment());

                ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(item, "w", null);

                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());

                byte[] buffer = new byte[4*1024];
                int read;

                while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    if(isCancelled())
                        break;
                    outputStream.write(buffer,0,read);
                }
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
                fos.close();
                contentResolver.update(item, values, null, null);
                values.clear();
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, 0);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            //Код для версий ниже Android 10
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Аудио записывается. Правда не совсем понимаю нужно ли для Android 10 и выше как-то иначе получить разрешение для работы с хранилищем. Сейчас код описанный выше в вопросе для получения разрешения дает разрешение и этот код записывает потоковое аудио. Если в моем коде есть ошибки или неправильная логика подправьте пожалуйста).